# Solving for and assigning the last remaining variable in a sympy expression

Tags: python, expression, sympy, variable-assignment, solver

This is a simplification of a more complex problem, in which, depending on previous input, a sympy exression needs to be solved with one remaining variable, where it is not known which variable that is.

I have figured out a way to solve for this remaining unknown value, but cannot then assign it to its proper name.

To model this:

```
import sympy as sp

c = sp.symbols('c',real=True)

Expr1 = 50*c - 5

solution  = sp.solve(Expr1,list(Expr1.free_symbols)[0])
print(solution)
```

The above code defines a simple expression with unknown value c. Since I'm trying to model a situation in which I don't know the name of the unknown variable, I have to use the term `list(Expr1.free_symbols)[0]` in the sympy.solve function to indicate for what variable to solve. This works, but now I'd like to also assign the found solution to the variable c, so that c = solution (Again, without knowing that the name of the last remaining variable was 'c'). Is there a way to do this?

I have tried in several ways to get the expression `list(Expr1.free_symbols)[0]` as a name for a new variable, like turning it into a dict element, but all attempts have simply raised errors.

Comment: Assigning a value to a 'unknown/dynamic' python variable (such as from a string) is awkward.  Usually it involves setting a key in the `globals` dict.  Here you have the added complication that the name comes from `symbol`.  Keep in mind your first line could have been `foobar=sp.symbols('c',real=True)`. The symbol name does not have to match the variable 'nane'.

Comment: `x=list(Expr1.free_symbols)[0]` is the symbol.  `x.name` is its name (e.g. 'c').  If you do `c=solution[[0]`, `c` is not long a symbol.  `globals()[x.name]` is `c`, the python variable as initially created.  So while it may possible to set a python varialbe 'dynamically', in general it isn't good python practice, and may be more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Making your own `dict` may be better, `{list(Expr1.free_symbols)[0].name:solution[0]}`

Comment: It would be better to take a step back and ask how to accomplish the broader problem for which you think that assigning to the c variable is a solution (this approach is almost certainly not the best way to solve the broader problem).

Comment: On Oscars advice I took a step back and solved the issue in a different way, by checking which of the remaining possible variables was still of the sympy.core.symbol.Symbol type and assigning the found solution to that variable.